# Communication between two c# applications

Tags: c#, web-services, communication

I have a problem, have not much experience in C #, so I did a lot of research and I'm stuck.

I have to make two applications C #, the first applications is windows forms, the second runs in the background, so that the first applications will be a (POS) sales point that need to communicate with the application background for information as (products, customers, etc ...) and send data, so do not want to use web service for problems like timeouts, so anyone can help me with some idea to perform this task?

it is important to mention that the application in background will be just one while the POS applcations wich will communicate with it will be a lot (n number of apps).

Comment: WCF services can use MSMQ to make sure messages do not get lost. So don't rule out web services too quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a myriad of ways of doing interprocess communication. As the question is so generic, I will point out some more common ways.

- The background process can be a windows service which updates the DB and POS systems query the DB to retrieve what they need. Even if the background process reads from the same DB, you can have a separate table which has "finished"  information ready for the POS piece to pick up. Now you can use a file instead of a DB to store this finished results too, but most folks prefer DB.
- You can use WCF channel to establish communication between the POS piece and the background process.
- You can convert your background process to a web-service and let your POS piece communicate using XML. I don't think any time-out issue should be a problem. You will have to explain better what time-out issue causes you to not use this option.
- You can convert the whole piece into a web-site and the POS will simply be a browser then
- You can use a bus like Tibco or MQ to pass data.
- Or you can go the old fashioned way of TCP sockets.

The most preferred way is usually the web-servcie or web-site way depending on your constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'll use a message queue for something like this.  They are a component in ensuring clean separation of concerns reducing and cross-application coupling and are meant to receive messages by some publisher (thus freeing the publisher of any further responsibility), and pushing messages to some subscriber.

RabbitMQ is a popular framework: https://www.rabbitmq.com/

(note that RabbitMQ (and other ready-built frameworks) can sometimes be daunting for new application programmers as they handle a great many use cases. However the underlying concept of writing to a queue from one application and reading from the queue in the other application is really the key here... feel free to implement a small utility of your own as a learning experience, but I do recommend an pre-existing framework if you're comfortable using such)

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use named pipes for such communications between different programs.

[How to: Use Named Pipes for Network Interprocess Communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use web service (based on soap protocol), 
you could attempt to use web api. In this way, you could build *rest based interfaces* with json (json streaming between computers is faster than xml streaming).

I think the following link can be usefull to you:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms